# Special characters not rendering properly in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, mathjax, mathml

I am converting MathML to SVG using Mathjax-node, while converting some special characters are not rendering properly

**MathML:**

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="math equation" display="inline" altimg-width="467" altimg-height="25" altimg="../images/altmath_5579.png"><mo>⤹</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>Σ</mo><msub><mi>M</mi><mrow><mi>A</mi></mrow></msub><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>;</mo><mspace width="10pt"/><mo>(</mo><mn>900</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">b</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>(</mo><mn>2</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>−</mo><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>F</mi><mrow><mi>B</mi><mi>D</mi></mrow></msub><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">s</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">i</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">n</mi><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>30</mn><mo>°</mo><mo>)</mo><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>10</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo mathvariant="normal">=</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
```

**SVG output:**

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="60.042ex" height="4.843ex" style="vertical-align: -1.838ex;" viewBox="0 -1293.7 25851.5 2085" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-labelledby="MathJax-SVG-1-Title">
<title id="MathJax-SVG-1-Title">math equation</title>
<defs aria-hidden="true">
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-2B" d="M56 237T56 250T70 270H369V420L370 570Q380 583 389 583Q402 583 409 568V270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H409V-68Q401 -82 391 -82H389H387Q375 -82 369 -68V230H70Q56 237 56 250Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-3A3" d="M666 247Q664 244 652 126T638 4V0H351Q131 0 95 0T57 5V6Q54 12 57 17L73 36Q89 54 121 90T182 159L305 299L56 644L55 658Q55 677 60 681Q63 683 351 683H638V679Q640 674 652 564T666 447V443H626V447Q618 505 604 543T559 605Q529 626 478 631T333 637H294H189L293 494Q314 465 345 422Q400 346 400 340Q400 338 399 337L154 57Q407 57 428 58Q476 60 508 68T551 83T575 103Q595 125 608 162T624 225L626 251H666V247Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMATHI-4D" d="M289 629Q289 635 232 637Q208 637 201 638T194 648Q194 649 196 659Q197 662 198 666T199 671T201 676T203 679T207 681T212 683T220 683T232 684Q238 684 262 684T307 683Q386 683 398 683T414 678Q415 674 451 396L487 117L510 154Q534 190 574 254T662 394Q837 673 839 675Q840 676 842 678T846 681L852 683H948Q965 683 988 683T1017 684Q1051 684 1051 673Q1051 668 1048 656T1045 643Q1041 637 1008 637Q968 636 957 634T939 623Q936 618 867 340T797 59Q797 55 798 54T805 50T822 48T855 46H886Q892 37 892 35Q892 19 885 5Q880 0 869 0Q864 0 828 1T736 2Q675 2 644 2T609 1Q592 1 592 11Q592 13 594 25Q598 41 602 43T625 46Q652 46 685 49Q699 52 704 61Q706 65 742 207T813 490T848 631L654 322Q458 10 453 5Q451 4 449 3Q444 0 433 0Q418 0 415 7Q413 11 374 317L335 624L267 354Q200 88 200 79Q206 46 272 46H282Q288 41 289 37T286 19Q282 3 278 1Q274 0 267 0Q265 0 255 0T221 1T157 2Q127 2 95 1T58 0Q43 0 39 2T35 11Q35 13 38 25T43 40Q45 46 65 46Q135 46 154 86Q158 92 223 354T289 629Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMATHI-41" d="M208 74Q208 50 254 46Q272 46 272 35Q272 34 270 22Q267 8 264 4T251 0Q249 0 239 0T205 1T141 2Q70 2 50 0H42Q35 7 35 11Q37 38 48 46H62Q132 49 164 96Q170 102 345 401T523 704Q530 716 547 716H555H572Q578 707 578 706L606 383Q634 60 636 57Q641 46 701 46Q726 46 726 36Q726 34 723 22Q720 7 718 4T704 0Q701 0 690 0T651 1T578 2Q484 2 455 0H443Q437 6 437 9T439 27Q443 40 445 43L449 46H469Q523 49 533 63L521 213H283L249 155Q208 86 208 74ZM516 260Q516 271 504 416T490 562L463 519Q447 492 400 412L310 260L413 259Q516 259 516 260Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-3D" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-30" d="M96 585Q152 666 249 666Q297 666 345 640T423 548Q460 465 460 320Q460 165 417 83Q397 41 362 16T301 -15T250 -22Q224 -22 198 -16T137 16T82 83Q39 165 39 320Q39 494 96 585ZM321 597Q291 629 250 629Q208 629 178 597Q153 571 145 525T137 333Q137 175 145 125T181 46Q209 16 250 16Q290 16 318 46Q347 76 354 130T362 333Q362 478 354 524T321 597Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-3B" d="M78 370Q78 394 95 412T138 430Q162 430 180 414T199 371Q199 346 182 328T139 310T96 327T78 370ZM78 60Q78 85 94 103T137 121Q202 121 202 8Q202 -44 183 -94T144 -169T118 -194Q115 -194 106 -186T95 -174Q94 -171 107 -155T137 -107T160 -38Q161 -32 162 -22T165 -4T165 4Q165 5 161 4T142 0Q110 0 94 18T78 60Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-28" d="M94 250Q94 319 104 381T127 488T164 576T202 643T244 695T277 729T302 750H315H319Q333 750 333 741Q333 738 316 720T275 667T226 581T184 443T167 250T184 58T225 -81T274 -167T316 -220T333 -241Q333 -250 318 -250H315H302L274 -226Q180 -141 137 -14T94 250Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-39" d="M352 287Q304 211 232 211Q154 211 104 270T44 396Q42 412 42 436V444Q42 537 111 606Q171 666 243 666Q245 666 249 666T257 665H261Q273 665 286 663T323 651T370 619T413 560Q456 472 456 334Q456 194 396 97Q361 41 312 10T208 -22Q147 -22 108 7T68 93T121 149Q143 149 158 135T173 96Q173 78 164 65T148 49T135 44L131 43Q131 41 138 37T164 27T206 22H212Q272 22 313 86Q352 142 352 280V287ZM244 248Q292 248 321 297T351 430Q351 508 343 542Q341 552 337 562T323 588T293 615T246 625Q208 625 181 598Q160 576 154 546T147 441Q147 358 152 329T172 282Q197 248 244 248Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-6C" d="M42 46H56Q95 46 103 60V68Q103 77 103 91T103 124T104 167T104 217T104 272T104 329Q104 366 104 407T104 482T104 542T103 586T103 603Q100 622 89 628T44 637H26V660Q26 683 28 683L38 684Q48 685 67 686T104 688Q121 689 141 690T171 693T182 694H185V379Q185 62 186 60Q190 52 198 49Q219 46 247 46H263V0H255L232 1Q209 2 183 2T145 3T107 3T57 1L34 0H26V46H42Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-62" d="M307 -11Q234 -11 168 55L158 37Q156 34 153 28T147 17T143 10L138 1L118 0H98V298Q98 599 97 603Q94 622 83 628T38 637H20V660Q20 683 22 683L32 684Q42 685 61 686T98 688Q115 689 135 690T165 693T176 694H179V543Q179 391 180 391L183 394Q186 397 192 401T207 411T228 421T254 431T286 439T323 442Q401 442 461 379T522 216Q522 115 458 52T307 -11ZM182 98Q182 97 187 90T196 79T206 67T218 55T233 44T250 35T271 29T295 26Q330 26 363 46T412 113Q424 148 424 212Q424 287 412 323Q385 405 300 405Q270 405 239 390T188 347L182 339V98Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-29" d="M60 749L64 750Q69 750 74 750H86L114 726Q208 641 251 514T294 250Q294 182 284 119T261 12T224 -76T186 -143T145 -194T113 -227T90 -246Q87 -249 86 -250H74Q66 -250 63 -250T58 -247T55 -238Q56 -237 66 -225Q221 -64 221 250T66 725Q56 737 55 738Q55 746 60 749Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-32" d="M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-66" d="M273 0Q255 3 146 3Q43 3 34 0H26V46H42Q70 46 91 49Q99 52 103 60Q104 62 104 224V385H33V431H104V497L105 564L107 574Q126 639 171 668T266 704Q267 704 275 704T289 705Q330 702 351 679T372 627Q372 604 358 590T321 576T284 590T270 627Q270 647 288 667H284Q280 668 273 668Q245 668 223 647T189 592Q183 572 182 497V431H293V385H185V225Q185 63 186 61T189 57T194 54T199 51T206 49T213 48T222 47T231 47T241 46T251 46H282V0H273Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-74" d="M27 422Q80 426 109 478T141 600V615H181V431H316V385H181V241Q182 116 182 100T189 68Q203 29 238 29Q282 29 292 100Q293 108 293 146V181H333V146V134Q333 57 291 17Q264 -10 221 -10Q187 -10 162 2T124 33T105 68T98 100Q97 107 97 248V385H18V422H27Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-2212" d="M84 237T84 250T98 270H679Q694 262 694 250T679 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMATHI-46" d="M48 1Q31 1 31 11Q31 13 34 25Q38 41 42 43T65 46Q92 46 125 49Q139 52 144 61Q146 66 215 342T285 622Q285 629 281 629Q273 632 228 634H197Q191 640 191 642T193 659Q197 676 203 680H742Q749 676 749 669Q749 664 736 557T722 447Q720 440 702 440H690Q683 445 683 453Q683 454 686 477T689 530Q689 560 682 579T663 610T626 626T575 633T503 634H480Q398 633 393 631Q388 629 386 623Q385 622 352 492L320 363H375Q378 363 398 363T426 364T448 367T472 374T489 386Q502 398 511 419T524 457T529 475Q532 480 548 480H560Q567 475 567 470Q567 467 536 339T502 207Q500 200 482 200H470Q463 206 463 212Q463 215 468 234T473 274Q473 303 453 310T364 317H309L277 190Q245 66 245 60Q245 46 334 46H359Q365 40 365 39T363 19Q359 6 353 0H336Q295 2 185 2Q120 2 86 2T48 1Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMATHI-42" d="M231 637Q204 637 199 638T194 649Q194 676 205 682Q206 683 335 683Q594 683 608 681Q671 671 713 636T756 544Q756 480 698 429T565 360L555 357Q619 348 660 311T702 219Q702 146 630 78T453 1Q446 0 242 0Q42 0 39 2Q35 5 35 10Q35 17 37 24Q42 43 47 45Q51 46 62 46H68Q95 46 128 49Q142 52 147 61Q150 65 219 339T288 628Q288 635 231 637ZM649 544Q649 574 634 600T585 634Q578 636 493 637Q473 637 451 637T416 636H403Q388 635 384 626Q382 622 352 506Q352 503 351 500L320 374H401Q482 374 494 376Q554 386 601 434T649 544ZM595 229Q595 273 572 302T512 336Q506 337 429 337Q311 337 310 336Q310 334 293 263T258 122L240 52Q240 48 252 48T333 46Q422 46 429 47Q491 54 543 105T595 229Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMATHI-44" d="M287 628Q287 635 230 637Q207 637 200 638T193 647Q193 655 197 667T204 682Q206 683 403 683Q570 682 590 682T630 676Q702 659 752 597T803 431Q803 275 696 151T444 3L430 1L236 0H125H72Q48 0 41 2T33 11Q33 13 36 25Q40 41 44 43T67 46Q94 46 127 49Q141 52 146 61Q149 65 218 339T287 628ZM703 469Q703 507 692 537T666 584T629 613T590 629T555 636Q553 636 541 636T512 636T479 637H436Q392 637 386 627Q384 623 313 339T242 52Q242 48 253 48T330 47Q335 47 349 47T373 46Q499 46 581 128Q617 164 640 212T683 339T703 469Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-73" d="M295 316Q295 356 268 385T190 414Q154 414 128 401Q98 382 98 349Q97 344 98 336T114 312T157 287Q175 282 201 278T245 269T277 256Q294 248 310 236T342 195T359 133Q359 71 321 31T198 -10H190Q138 -10 94 26L86 19L77 10Q71 4 65 -1L54 -11H46H42Q39 -11 33 -5V74V132Q33 153 35 157T45 162H54Q66 162 70 158T75 146T82 119T101 77Q136 26 198 26Q295 26 295 104Q295 133 277 151Q257 175 194 187T111 210Q75 227 54 256T33 318Q33 357 50 384T93 424T143 442T187 447H198Q238 447 268 432L283 424L292 431Q302 440 314 448H322H326Q329 448 335 442V310L329 304H301Q295 310 295 316Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-69" d="M69 609Q69 637 87 653T131 669Q154 667 171 652T188 609Q188 579 171 564T129 549Q104 549 87 564T69 609ZM247 0Q232 3 143 3Q132 3 106 3T56 1L34 0H26V46H42Q70 46 91 49Q100 53 102 60T104 102V205V293Q104 345 102 359T88 378Q74 385 41 385H30V408Q30 431 32 431L42 432Q52 433 70 434T106 436Q123 437 142 438T171 441T182 442H185V62Q190 52 197 50T232 46H255V0H247Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-6E" d="M41 46H55Q94 46 102 60V68Q102 77 102 91T102 122T103 161T103 203Q103 234 103 269T102 328V351Q99 370 88 376T43 385H25V408Q25 431 27 431L37 432Q47 433 65 434T102 436Q119 437 138 438T167 441T178 442H181V402Q181 364 182 364T187 369T199 384T218 402T247 421T285 437Q305 442 336 442Q450 438 463 329Q464 322 464 190V104Q464 66 466 59T477 49Q498 46 526 46H542V0H534L510 1Q487 2 460 2T422 3Q319 3 310 0H302V46H318Q379 46 379 62Q380 64 380 200Q379 335 378 343Q372 371 358 385T334 402T308 404Q263 404 229 370Q202 343 195 315T187 232V168V108Q187 78 188 68T191 55T200 49Q221 46 249 46H265V0H257L234 1Q210 2 183 2T145 3Q42 3 33 0H25V46H41Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-33" d="M127 463Q100 463 85 480T69 524Q69 579 117 622T233 665Q268 665 277 664Q351 652 390 611T430 522Q430 470 396 421T302 350L299 348Q299 347 308 345T337 336T375 315Q457 262 457 175Q457 96 395 37T238 -22Q158 -22 100 21T42 130Q42 158 60 175T105 193Q133 193 151 175T169 130Q169 119 166 110T159 94T148 82T136 74T126 70T118 67L114 66Q165 21 238 21Q293 21 321 74Q338 107 338 175V195Q338 290 274 322Q259 328 213 329L171 330L168 332Q166 335 166 348Q166 366 174 366Q202 366 232 371Q266 376 294 413T322 525V533Q322 590 287 612Q265 626 240 626Q208 626 181 615T143 592T132 580H135Q138 579 143 578T153 573T165 566T175 555T183 540T186 520Q186 498 172 481T127 463Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-B0" d="M147 628Q147 669 179 692T244 715Q298 715 325 689T352 629Q352 592 323 567T249 542Q202 542 175 567T147 628ZM313 628Q313 660 300 669T259 678H253Q248 678 242 678T234 679Q217 679 207 674T192 659T188 644T187 629Q187 600 198 590Q210 579 250 579H265Q279 579 288 581T305 595T313 628Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJMAIN-31" d="M213 578L200 573Q186 568 160 563T102 556H83V602H102Q149 604 189 617T245 641T273 663Q275 666 285 666Q294 666 302 660V361L303 61Q310 54 315 52T339 48T401 46H427V0H416Q395 3 257 3Q121 3 100 0H88V46H114Q136 46 152 46T177 47T193 50T201 52T207 57T213 61V578Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJSZ2-28" d="M180 96T180 250T205 541T266 770T353 944T444 1069T527 1150H555Q561 1144 561 1141Q561 1137 545 1120T504 1072T447 995T386 878T330 721T288 513T272 251Q272 133 280 56Q293 -87 326 -209T399 -405T475 -531T536 -609T561 -640Q561 -643 555 -649H527Q483 -612 443 -568T353 -443T266 -270T205 -41Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E4-MJSZ2-29" d="M35 1138Q35 1150 51 1150H56H69Q113 1113 153 1069T243 944T330 771T391 541T416 250T391 -40T330 -270T243 -443T152 -568T69 -649H56Q43 -649 39 -647T35 -637Q65 -607 110 -548Q283 -316 316 56Q324 133 324 251Q324 368 316 445Q278 877 48 1123Q36 1137 35 1138Z"></path>
</defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" aria-hidden="true">
<text font-family="Arial Unicode MS" stroke="none" transform="scale(71.759) matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)">⤹</text>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-2B" x="887" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-3A3" x="1666" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(2388,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMATHI-4D" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E4-MJMATHI-41" x="1372" y="-230"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-3D" x="4267" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="5323" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-3B" x="5824" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-28" x="7269" y="-1"></use>
<g transform="translate(7867,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-39"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="500" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="1001" y="0"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-6C" x="9698" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-62" x="9977" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-29" x="10533" y="-1"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-28" x="11131" y="-1"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-32" x="11728" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-66" x="12559" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-74" x="12931" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-29" x="13321" y="-1"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-2212" x="14140" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-28" x="15141" y="-1"></use>
<g transform="translate(15739,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMATHI-46" x="0" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(643,-150)">
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E4-MJMATHI-42" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E4-MJMATHI-44" x="759" y="0"></use>
</g>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-73" x="17935" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-69" x="18329" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-6E" x="18608" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(19494,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-33"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="500" y="0"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-B0" x="20495" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJSZ2-29" x="20996" y="-1"></use>
<g transform="translate(21923,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-31"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="500" y="0"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-66" x="23254" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-74" x="23627" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-3D" x="24294" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E4-MJMAIN-30" x="25351" y="0"></use>
</g>
</svg>
```

So when converting the SVG, the "⤹" not rendering properly (see below)

[image]

but when using "&#x2939;" instead of "⤹" rendering properly (see below)

[image]

Any way to do this using "⤹" directly ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is probably buried inside MathJax - it's not recognzing that as a convertible character. The first SVG path in your converted source renders the plus sign, so it's not an SVG problem.

Comment: @MichaelMullany, FYI, the SVG path you are referring to is part of a `<defs>` tag, so is not displayed at that location.  It is a table of paths used later when the actual paths are placed within the expression via the `<use>` tags later on.  The include href links to the path elements in the `<defs>` tag.  So the first displayable node is actually the `<text>` node I mention in my answer below.

Comment: Ah. "Read the code Michael"

Comment: This works just fine on my Windows 10 machine across all browsers. Arial Unicode MS is an Office font, but should also be installed on OSX 10.5 and higher. Are you doing this on Linux? Or Old OSX? (Or iOS?)

Answer (score 2):

Not all characters are available in the default MathJax TeX font.  For those, MathJax inserts `<text>` tags in hopes that there will be a font installed on your system that *does* include the needed character.  You can see this in your output as the first element inside the first `<g>` tag:

```
<text font-family="Arial Unicode MS" stroke="none" transform="scale(71.759) matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)">⤹</text>
```

Depending on your browser and the fonts installed on your system, this may or may not actually show a character.  (E.g., in Windows, especially in IE, this doesn't always work, even when there is a font installed that does contain the character.)

You could configure MathJax to use a font with more coverage, say STIX-Web, by placing

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  SVG: {font: "STIX-Web"}
});
</script>
```

*before* the script that loads `MathJax.js` itself.

Comment: @dpvc the OP was using MathJax-node.

Comment: @pkra, right, sorry.  In that case, use `--font STIX-Web` on the command line tools, or `mjAPI.config({MathJax: {SVG: {font: 'STIX-Web'}}});` if you are calling the mathjax-node API directly.